# HTML2Canvas not working, need to console image url

Tags: jquery, html2canvas

I am trying to screenshot the view of a div which contains fullcalendar, but unable to do so. I have tried following code:

```
  function screenshot(){
     alert('zz'); html2canvas(document.querySelector('#calendar')).then(function(canvas) {
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        console.log(canvas.toDataURL());
     });
    }
```

Whenever I click on screenshot, I want to capture image of `div#calendar` and need to console the url so that I can use this image later as thumbnail when I share this page link later in social media.

You can check it here on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/prying/pen/rEKWXJ?editors=1010)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below function to get image using html2canvas..

```
function screenshot(){
      console.log(html2canvas(document.querySelector('#calendar')))
      html2canvas(document.querySelector('#calendar'), {
      onrendered: function(canvas) {  
        var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        console.log("image => ",image); //image in base64
        var pHtml = "<img src="+image+" />";
        $("#parent").append(pHtml); //you can append image tag anywhere
        }
     });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is working perfectly, just add base64 to the src of the img tag as Ravi suggested. If you take the base64 generated in console.log and paste it into a base64 to image conversion tool, you will see that the image is being rendered.

Remove the part "data:image/png;base64," part, and then paste the rest of the base64 code into some online tool like https://www.ipvoid.com/base64-to-png/ and submit the form to view the generated image.